# How to use the formula property in NHibernate mapping

Tags: nhibernate, formula

I have a question regarding how to use the formula property to be used in the SQL where clause. Sepcifically, I'd like to use (datepart(hh, getdate())) as the formula and the resulting SQL that I expect is

> Select select_list from table_name
>   where (datepart(hh, getdate()))  < 17

But I kept the where clause like this:

> where (this_0_.hh, getdate())) <= 17

I am not sure why the alias is inserted before the "hh" date part.

Any help on how to get this where clause right is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alias is inserted because the parser doesn't know `hh` is a literal (if MS had used a string, you wouldn't have this problem, as you'd be able to use `'hh'` without a problem)

The easiest workaround is creating a function (call it `gethour`) that returns `datepart(hh, getdate())`.

Comment: `Yes it works indeed. It is a shame though that we have to resort to a workaround for this fairly commonly used MS SQL keyword. It works for me now. Hopefully NHibernate will fix this issue in a future release.`

Comment: @John: keep in mind that NHibernate works for multiple databases. Modifying the parser to address a MSSQL annoyance is unlikely.

Comment: @Diego, since it is declared in the configuration file that it is for a specific sql dialect and NHibernate always knows how to handle a couple of MS SQL keywords, you would think it is logical that NHibernate takes care of all the keywords. but again we just have to know and live within limits sometimes.

Comment: @John: hh is not a keyword. It's a pseudo-literal *only* in the context of the `datepart` function.